# How to create rss status filter

Tags: rss, ibm-cloud, status

I've seen the bluemix status rss feed on 
https://status.eu-gb.bluemix.net/api/feed/notifications/feed.rss
and I've seen the same feed and dashboard on https://status.eu-gb.bluemix.net/

However, on the dashboard it's possible to filter the feed.

Is it possible to filter the rss feed as well?

For example "/feed/notifications/feed.rss?type=incident&region=eu-gb"
Or alternatively are there individual feed sources for each region/type/etc?

Can't find this documented anywhere -- even when using the powerful google machine

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this functionality is not available because the RSS feed does not differentiate by notification type nor region. If this functionality would help you, you can add it to the IBM Bluemix Ideas site, which is available at the following URL: https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas